# How to trigger the implicit intent from Dialog in android?

Tags: android

I am using the share dialog for selecting the image to upload in the local database however I couldn't start the activity for result to capture the URI link.

The code is as below:

```
selectImage = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.selectImage);

selectImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //code to fethc the image form the local strorage
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI );
            startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    });
```

Comment: What error do you get? Can you update your question with logs?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add type as "image" using   **`setType()`**  since you want to choose image,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI );    
intent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), req_code);
```

And also check whether the click listener is working.

Comment: Actually dialog is set through the constructor and above code is not in any Activity class ...so startActivityForResult() is showing an error.... Thank you !!!